# Deep RL for healthcare: existing benchmarking datasets or environments

Tags: reinforcement-learning, data-sets

I am currently a Ph.D. student in the computer science department, I was given the subject of Deep RL for Healthcare. However, after lots of research on the internet, I could not find any free dataset or environment to develop/test my algorithms against. It seems that till now, RL and Deep RL is still focused on games applications such as atari environments, etc. Although there is a significant number of papers that applied RL in healthcare, the dataset or environment model used is not given.
So my question is: is there any known existing dataset or simulation environment (like openAI gym environments) for Deep RL application in healthcare ?